# Is there a simple way to format (set color based on value) a share-point column without writing any of the JSON code

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I am trying to do conditional formatting of a column in a sharepoint list. My need is fairly simple. The column is a "choice" type field - with 6 possible values. For each of these values, I would like the column to be shown in a specific color (m:n mapping, n

I tried using the recommended JSON code, it ended up being far too complicated because of the extreme amount of nesting.

Comment: Yes, depending on the version of SharePoint that your are using. Version (2013, 2016, etc)? SharePoint Online or On-Prem?

Comment: Thank you @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP. I am using SharePoint Online

Comment: Sorry, I've got an easy solution, but it's blocked in SharePoint Online. (https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2018/01/adding-html-to-sharepoint-columns-color.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use modern list in SharePoint online, we can use the OOTB formatting like below.

[image]

If you only want to color the text, the JSON formatting also easy.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'A', '#ff0000', if(@currentField=='B','#11ff00',if(@currentField=='C','#1111ff',if(@currentField=='D','#aa3344',if(@currentField=='E','#22aa44','#3344aa')))))"
  }
}
```

[image]

If you use the classic list view, we can use JSLINK to achieve it, the following article with code for your reference.

[SharePoint list conditional formatting with JSLink](https://nearbaseline.com/2013/12/sharepoint-list-conditional-formatting-with-jslink/)